# Problem with aspnet_regsql.exe

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i wrote a website with `asp.net` 4 and `sql server` 2008. But my host `sql` version is 2005 so i get script from my database in `sqlserver` 2008 and convert it to 2005. Then  i import `.sql` file that is exported from 2008 iin `sqlserver` 2005 and retrieve  it. Then i make a back up with `sqlserver` 2005 and upload it on my host. Now i have one problem:
I used aspnet_regsql.exe to create the database schema.
But when i want to login to my website it throws following error:

> The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database
>   schema compatible with schema version '1'.  However, the current
>   database schema is not compatible with this version.  You may need to
>   either install a compatible schema with `aspnet_regsql.exe` (available
>   in the framework installation directory), or upgrade the provider to a
>   newer version.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ASP.NET is your published website using? It looks like it might be different than what you're using in development.

The version info is configured on a per-AppPool basis in IIS.